# How to convert an ASCII JSON 3D model file to binary?

Tags: javascript, json, 3d, three.js

While looking into some webGL examples (mostly Three.js based examples) I noticed large models are loaded via a combination of ASCII+binary JSON. This approach is very attractive to me because of the reduced file size.
The ASCII JSON has the general format of (taken from Three.js example, webgl_geometry_large_mesh.html) :

```
{

    "metadata" :
    {
        "formatVersion" : 3,
        "sourceFile"    : "lucy100k.obj",
        "generatedBy"   : "OBJConverter",
        "vertices"      : 50002,
        "faces"         : 100000,
        "normals"       : 0,
        "uvs"           : 0,
        "materials"     : 0
    },

    "materials": [  {
    "DbgColor" : 15658734,
    "DbgIndex" : 0,
    "DbgName" : "default"
    }],

    "buffers": "Lucy100k_bin.bin"

}
```

As seen above, instead of a section containing a truck-load of vertices, normals, UVs, etc it is all packed into the referred binary file. Does anyone know how to create that binary file? Can I do it with Blender? If not, is there a script I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this line:

```
"generatedBy"   : "OBJConverter"
```

That file was generated by `OBJConverter` (from some .obj and .mtl files).

`OBJConverter` is a Python script called `convert_obj_three.py` sited in `three.js / utils / converters / obj`.

The own script has a comment about "How to get proper OBJ + MTL files with Blender".

Comment: ``convert_obj_three.py`` updated site is ``three.js / utils / converters / obj``.